# How to select first item without long press using RecyclerView's SelectionTracker

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm building an application that will allow users to pick from a RecyclerView list, highlighting their choice. The problem is that in order to highlight an item for the first time, a long press is needed. (Afterwards, a short click is enough to do the selection.)

I haven't found anything in the documentation to indicate why this happens.

I'm using [SelectionTracker](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/recyclerview/selection/SelectionTracker?hl=en/)

Specifically following this [guide](https://proandroiddev.com/a-guide-to-recyclerview-selection-3ed9f2381504)

**Here's the code** : 
https://github.com/marcosholgado/multiselection

**Expectations:**
I expect the item on the RecyclerView to be selected every time someone  short clicks on it.

**Reality:**
In order to select an item for the first time, the user needs to long press it.

Any Ideas?

Comment: So scenario should be like Google Photos App. Once long press then photo will be selected and after that you just need to click on photo for selection.

Comment: This sounds similar, yes. However, I don't want this to happen.

Comment: Okay. So everytime you want to long press click for selection?

Comment: Every time I want a short press click for selection.

Comment: Short press means it will be simply click

Comment: Yes. On every (short) click, an item can be selected.
(I edited the question to clarify)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Just override SelectionHotspot to return true. That's all you need

```
fun getItemDetails(): ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long> =
            object : ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails<Long>() {
                override fun getPosition(): Int = adapterPosition
                override fun getSelectionKey(): Long? = itemId
                override fun inSelectionHotspot(e: MotionEvent): Boolean { return true }
            }
```

Comment: I have done that but it doesn't work. It behaves differently on API 21 and API 26 using the android studio emulator. Returning false in inSelectionHotspot () allows long press for selection in API 21 but still single press on API 26. I want to enforce the long press on API 26.

Comment: @DeKekem if you want long press, then don't override `inSelectionHotspot` method. Its default behavior is long press to select first item.

Answer (score 3):

While I couldn't think of a solution that doesn't involve reimplementing both a `MotionInputHandler` and a `SelectionTracker.Builder` (as mentioned in the guide), there is a neat trick to achieve the behaviour you want.

We know that the `TouchInputHandler` selects items on single click as long as the `SelectionTracker` is not empty. That means if we have some special key saved in the `SelectoinTracker` that's not associated with a real list item we practically 'activate' the on single click selection mode this way. However we also have to make sure that our `KeyProvider` doesn't provide that same special key to keep our data consistent.

So assuming you have picked a special key, say `ghostKey`, activating and deactivating the selection mode is now a matter of calling `mSelectionTracker.select(ghostkey)` or `mSelectionTracker.clearSelection()`. You can then execute these calls however you like, be that having a button that activates and deactivates the selection mode or simply calling that during the hosting view creation process i.e `onCreate`, `onCreateView` etc..

If you are using Kotlin you can also define some Extensions that wrap these calls for you, so you'd be able to do things like `mSelectionTracker.enable()` or `mSelectionTracker.disable()`

Comment: Also beware that `mSelectionTracker.hasSelection()` will now return true as long as the 'selection mode' is enabled even if no visible items are selected. So you might want to make extra checks to assure that items are really selected.

Comment: Thank you for your answer ! If I understand correctly, you're suggesting I select a non-existing item before the first selection and after any deselection, so as to skip the long click ?

Comment: Yes, basically having an imaginary item selected in the background as long as real items should be selected on single click

Comment: I check if ```mSelectionTracker.hasSelection()``` only on ```onSelectionChanged() ```, so it seems to work. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Use this line

> selectionTracker.select(item.getSelectionKey());

On this override method

```
 .withOnItemActivatedListener(new OnItemActivatedListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onItemActivated(@NonNull ItemDetailsLookup.ItemDetails item, @NonNull MotionEvent e) {
                    selectionTracker.select(item.getSelectionKey());
                    return true;
                }
            })
```

I solved like this. Keep coding..

Answer (score 1):

In your ViewHolder, set `onClickListener` and in that check whether you have any selected items using `SelectionTracker.hasSelection()` and if it returns false, just select that item using `SelectionTracker.select(getItemDetails().getSelectionKey())`
like this:

```
itemView.setOnClickListener(v -> {
    if (!tracker.hasSelection())
        tracker.select(getItemDetails().getSelectionKey());
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I did:

```
binding.root.setOnClickListener {
   tracker?.let {
     if(!it.hasSelection()) it.select(binding.currItem?.uuid!!)
        binding.setVariable(BR.selected, it.isSelected(binding.currItem?.uuid))
     }

     binding.executePendingBindings()
}
```

I implemented a click listener on the view with the check if the selection tracker has any selected entity or not. If it does not have any selection then I explicitly added the selection and the selection tracker gets enabled automatically.

I think this must the solution you were looking for.

Answer (score 0):

**The RecyclerView-selection framework is not designed to handle either of the following scenarios!!**

A.) An 'enable multiselect' button that toggles the multi-selection on-and-off.

B.) RecyclerView Adapters that utilize more than one row ViewType that must not be selectable.

*If your scope requires A.) or B.) (above), do NOT use the RecyclerView-selection framework.

**Instead, remove it and do the following:**

1.) Add a Post-Api data field to your list item model:

```
var isMultiSelected: Boolean = false // User has highlighted this inbox's row for multi-selection
```

2.) Create a Listener to communicate from the Adapter to the Fragment/Activity:

```
class MyFragment : MyFragmentListener {
interface MyFragmentListener {
    fun myDataModelOnClick(myDataModel: MyDataModel)
    fun engageMultiSelect(selectedDataModelCount: Int)
    fun disengageMultiSelect()
}
override fun engageMultiSelect(selectedMyModelCount: Int) {
    // Update the fragment view for multi-select engaged conditions
    selectedCount_textView.text = selectedMyModelCount.toString()
}

override fun disengageMultiSelect() {
// Update the fragment view for multi-select engaged conditions
}
```

3.) Update your Adapter.onBindViewHolder() to use the new field

```
holder.enableMultiSelectionButton.setOnClickListener {
    myModel.isMultiSelected = true
    myModel.engageMultiSelect(getMultiSelectionCount()) // Enable multi-selection
    notifyItemChanged(position)
}
holder.rowConstraintLayout.setOnClickListener {
    if (getMultiSelectionCount() > 0) { // Is multi-selection engaged?
        myModel.isMultiSelected = !myModel.isMultiSelected
        if (getMultiSelectionCount() > 0) { // New Item Count may still be larger than 0
            myModelListener.engageMultiSelect(getMultiSelectionCount())
        } else {
            myModelListener.disengageMultiSelect()
        }
        notifyItemChanged(position)
    } else {
        // Normal 'tap' when multi-selection is not engaged
    }
}
holder.rowConstraintLayout.setOnLongClickListener {
    myModel.isMultiSelected = !myModel.isMultiSelected
    if (getMultiSelectionCount() > 0) { // Is multi-selection engaged?
        myModelListener.engageMultiSelect(getMultiSelectionCount())
    } else {
        myModelListener.disengageMultiSelect()
    }
    notifyItemChanged(position)
    true
}
if (myModel.isMultiSelected) {
    holder.rowConstraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(R.id.coolcolor)
} else {
    holder.rowConstraintLayout.setBackgroundColor(R.id.white)
}
```

Comment: You can add the MyModelFragmentListener to MyModelAdapter in the MyModelAdapter constructor
class MyModelAdapter(private val myModelFragmentListener: myModelFragmentListener)